# undefined method `keys' for array trying to factor out gem logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fusioncharts

I'm using a gem called Fusion Charts to make graphs for me, but the instructions have way more than I'd like in the controller.

Here is a call that works.

```
weights_over_time = []

weights.each do |weight|
  weights_over_time.push({
    label: weight.created_at.strftime("%m-%-d-%y"),
    value: weight.weight,
  })
end
@weights_chart = Fusioncharts::Chart.new({
    type: 'line',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '400',
    height: '300',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
        "chart": {
        "caption": "Weight over time",
        "xAxisName": "Date",
        "yAxisName": "Weight",
        "lineThickness": "2",
        "paletteColors": "#0075c2",
        "baseFontColor": "#333333",
        "baseFont": "Helvetica Neue,Arial",
        "captionFontSize": "14",
        "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
        "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
        "showBorder": "0",
        "bgColor": "#ffffff",
        "showShadow": "0",
        "canvasBgColor": "#ffffff",
        "canvasBorderAlpha": "0",
        "divlineAlpha": "100",
        "divlineColor": "#999999",
        "divlineThickness": "1",
        "divLineIsDashed": "1",
        "divLineDashLen": "1",
        "divLineGapLen": "1",
        "showXAxisLine": "1",
        "xAxisLineThickness": "1",
        "xAxisLineColor": "#999999",
        "showAlternateHGridColor": "0"
            },
            data: weights_over_time
        }
    })
  end
```

Here is my attempt to put most of this in the model, this results in 'undefined method `keys` for array.  I figured if I could initialize all the json that's static with the dynamic data as an argument it could work. I tried turning the array to a hash with Hash[*array] and I get "odd number of arguments for Hash."

```
class Example
  class Fusioncharts::Chart
    def initialize(weights_over_time)
      self.chart {
        type: 'area2d',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '400',
        height: '300',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
          "chart": {
            "caption": "Weight over time",
            "xAxisName": "Date",
            "yAxisName": "Weight",
            "paletteColors": "#0075c2",
            "bgColor": "#ffffff",
            "showBorder": "0",
            "showCanvasBorder": "0",
            "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
            "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
            "plotFillAlpha": "50",
            "showXAxisLine": "1",
            "axisLineAlpha": "25",
            "divLineAlpha": "10",
            "showValues": "1",
            "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
            "captionFontSize": "14",
            "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
            "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
            "toolTipColor": "#ffffff",
            "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
            "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
            "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
            "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
            "toolTipPadding": "5"
          },
          data: weights_over_time
        }
      }
    end
  end
end

class ExamplesController < ApplicationController
  def fc_json

    @user = current_user
    @weights = @user.weights.all
    weights = @weights.select(:weight, :created_at)
    weights_over_time = []

    weights.each do |weight|
      weights_over_time.push(
        weights: {
          x: weight.created_at,
          y: weight.weight
        }
      )
    end
    @chart = Fusioncharts::Chart.new(weights_over_time)
  end 
end
```

I certainly welcome any critique to make employ best practices/make it more readable, but I most care about not having all this in my controllers.

Error message:

NoMethodError in ExamplesController#fc_json
undefined method `keys' for #

Highlighting this line:

@chart = Fusioncharts::Chart.new(weights_over_time)

Here is the full trace.

```
fusioncharts-rails (0.0.2) lib/fusioncharts/rails/chart.rb:115:in `parse_options'
fusioncharts-rails (0.0.2) lib/fusioncharts/rails/chart.rb:16:in `initialize'
app/controllers/examples_controller.rb:19:in `new'
app/controllers/examples_controller.rb:19:in `fc_json'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/Users/gabepressman1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/gabepressman1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/gabepressman1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Is this actually your code? It doesn't seem like your class should even be parsable. (`initialize` is inside `self.chart{`, and there's no closing curly brace?)

Comment: Could you also share the actual error message?

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment, I think this might be the right fix for your code, though I'm wondering if there was just a copy/paste issue with the code you shared. (If this doesn't solve the problem, please fix up the code in the question and give us more information about the error, like the full stack trace.)

```
class Example
  class Fusioncharts::Chart
    def initialize(weights_over_time)
      self.chart {
        type: 'area2d',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '400',
        height: '300',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
          "chart": {
            "caption": "Weight over time",
            "xAxisName": "Date",
            "yAxisName": "Weight",
            "paletteColors": "#0075c2",
            "bgColor": "#ffffff",
            "showBorder": "0",
            "showCanvasBorder": "0",
            "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
            "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
            "plotFillAlpha": "50",
            "showXAxisLine": "1",
            "axisLineAlpha": "25",
            "divLineAlpha": "10",
            "showValues": "1",
            "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
            "captionFontSize": "14",
            "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
            "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
            "toolTipColor": "#ffffff",
            "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
            "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
            "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
            "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
            "toolTipPadding": "5"
          },
          data: weights_over_time
        }
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @pressline47 Can you update the question with the current code you're running?